# Ruby: Find first N regex matches in a string (and stop scanning)

Tags: ruby, regex, performance

Wanting to scan a very long string for regex matches. Wondering what would be the most efficient way to find the first N regex's. e.g. Something like:

```
'abcabcabc'.scan /b/, limit: 2
```

would end successfully after 5 characters, if only scan supported a limit option.

(The string is several MB - a memoized data structure in memory - and this is a web request. Perf matters.)

Comment: I think you should implement your own `scan` function with the limit, by using `match` method with starting index parameter in Regexp class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that elegant, but you could use the block form:

```
str = 'abcabcabc'

result = []
str.scan(/b/) { |match| result << match; break if result.size >= 2 }
result #=> ["b", "b"]
```

Comment: I can see from Ruby 2.3.1 source code that this will do what OP wants:    `while (!NIL_P(result = scan_once(str, pat, &start))) {
        last = prev;
        prev = start;
        rb_yield(result);
        str_mod_check(str, p, len);
    }` It could be version-dependent though.

Comment: @NeilSlater So you're suggesting the block form is "streamed" such that yields can happen before the string has been fully scanned?

Comment: @mahemoff yes, you can verify this by running the above for a very large string.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, Ruby regex supports [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), so you can use it like this:

```
'abcabcabc'.match(/(b).*?(b)/)
```

Adding `?` after `.*` makes it mach lazily, stopping as soon as the regex has been fulfilled. From the [Regexp class repetition documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition):

> Repetition is greedy by default: as many occurrences as possible are matched while still allowing the overall match to succeed. By contrast, lazy matching makes the minimal amount of matches necessary for overall success. A greedy metacharacter can be made lazy by following it with ?.

Comment: Yes, this could work with some computation to compose the regex, something like `multiples = #{regex}*limit; /#{multiples.join '.*?'}/`