# Different and same Regex in Ruby and JS on the same input

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

This is the input line `"!!!??"`

FIRST regex works similar in Ruby and JS and do what it need to do split this input for two lines contains "!" and "?" respectively:

**Example #1 ruby like js** `/!+|\?+/g`

RUBY `s.scan(/!+|\?+/).inspect` works like as  JS `s.match(/!+|\?+/g)`. 
And output is: RUBY `[ '!!!', '??' ]`, JS `[\"!!!\", \"??\"]`

**Example #2 ruby is not js** `/([?!])\1*/`

Here ruby and js have different behavior 
RUBY `s.scan(/([?!])\1*/)` not equal to JS `s.match(/([?!])\1*/g)`.
RUBY returns two arrays `[[\"!\"], [\"?\"]]`. 
JS returns two strings as like as in the Example #1 `[ '!!!', '??' ]`.

Why `/([?!])\1*/` acts different in Ruby and JS?

code https://goo.gl/

Comment: @musefan `match` only returns a single match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't know ruby, I just [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993662/whats-the-difference-between-scan-and-match-on-ruby-string) and thought it looked correct, but on second look it seems you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) only returns captured substrings when capturing group(s) is/are defined in the pattern, you should modify the pattern to capture the whole match and add some more Ruby code (edited [as per this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548744/different-and-same-regex-in-ruby-and-js-on-the-same-input/47548987?noredirect=1#comment82055107_47548987)):

```
s="!!!??"
matches = s.scan(/(([?!])\2*)/).inject([]) { |acc, (m, _)| acc << m }
puts matches
# = ['!!!', '??']
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/LBr98Y).

As per [@mudasobwa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548744/different-and-same-regex-in-ruby-and-js-on-the-same-input/47548987#comment82054608_47548987), you may even contract that to

```
"!!!??".scan(/(([?!])\2*)/).map(&:first)
```

Here, `(([?!])\2*)` matches the same texts as `/([?!])\1*/`, but since the whole pattern is wrapped with capturing parentheses, the backreference to the `?` or `!` now has ID=2, hence `\1` turns into `\2`. Inside the block, there is access to both the captured values via `m` (the whole match) and `n` (`?` or `!`). We are only collecting whole matches, hence `m` is added to `matches` upon each match.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, this shorthand will make it shorter. Just in case anyone wants to have some "technical" access to the second capturing group, the expanded version might still be of value.

Comment: The expanded version should be `"!!!??".scan(/(([?!])\2*)/).inject({}) { |acc, (m, _)| acc << m }` without leaking an accumulator to the global space with a local variable :)

Comment: @mudasobwa That is interesting. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39386386/3832970) when posting, and I bet you could say the same about that one, right?

Comment: Yes. And we can summon @Stefan to confirm :)